# Hibernate uuid generation gets 'data too long' error

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following error while persisting into a table at mysql using hibernate:

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'REQUEST_ID' at row 1
ERROR [some.class.ClassImpl] persist failed: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'REQUEST_ID' at row 1
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

Here is how I used generated value uuid for my primary key

```
@Id
@Column(name="REQUEST_ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
```

And here is my column at `mysql` database:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| REQUEST_ID          | varchar(32)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that "uuid2" generates a UUID with dashes in it, e.g.

`4d8bef3d-f46f-4f4e-8cad-673feaed896c`

Try setting your database column to:

`varchar(36)`

and optionally update your annotations to the following:

`@Column(name="REQUEST_ID", length=36)`

`@Length(min=36, max=36)`

Answer (score 0):

use  `@Column(name="REQUEST_ID", length=32)`, currently your variable char length that is being generated is greater than 32. You can also use `@Length(max=32)`

**update:**  as @cliff.meyers answer **uuid2** do use four '-' in generated string according to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-hilodescription) hibernate document **uuid2** uses `org.hibernate.id.uuid.StandardRandomStrategy` as default Generation Strategy which uses

> "version 3" (aka, "random") UUID values via the randomUUID method of java.util.UUID

which by [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_3_.28MD5_hash.29) reference specified as 36 character long. You need to either change `REQUEST_ID` to `varchar(36)` or use `strategy = "uuid"` which is `string of 32 hexidecimal digits`.

Comment: After following your answer I am now facing this error `ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='length must be between 0 and 32'`.